# Hiding Eggs Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

How can I figure out if I have 6 red eggs, 3 blue eggs, 1 green egg, and 2 yellow eggs. Aside from their color, they are identical. I have 12 different hiding spots, each big enough for 1 egg. How many ways are there to hide the eggs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: How many ways are there to choose $6$ of the $12$ hiding places for the red eggs? Once you’ve done that, how many ways are there to choose $3$ of the remaining hiding places for the blue eggs? Keep going in this fashion and combine the answers correctly, and you’ll have your answer.

Comment: So this leads me to think I want to do 12C6 * 6C3 * 3C1 * 2C2. Is this how I would combine them correctly?

Comment: @Nate: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint(In terms of Combinatorics): How many ways can you partition 12 items in groups of 6, 3, 2 and 1?